# Were there crewmen from other USN ships on USS Missouri when the Japanese surrendered?

Tags: united-states, world-war-two, military, japan, naval

I have tried finding a list of the crewmen on the USS Missouri at the time of the signing of the  Japanese Instrument of Surrender, or at least some general information about who was on the ship at that time, but nothing that I've found is really helpful. I'm wondering if, aside from some dignitaries and high-level officers from other militarizes or branches of the US military, if any non-Missouri crew were present on the ship? If some said they were present at the signing of the JIS, is there a way to verify this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost certainly.

For example Admiral Bruce Fraser, the British signatory to the *surrender document*, [hosted "notable allied leaders" on his flagship, **HMS Duke of York**](http://www.navy.gov.au/sites/default/files/documents/Hobbs_THE_BRITISH_PACIFIC_FLEET_IN_1945.pdf), in ceremonies ancillary and supplementary to the surrender itself.

> The British Pacific Fleet achieved its aim and ensured that a British admiral was present to sign the Japanese surrender document on board the **USS Missouri** in Tokyo Bay on 2 September 1945. He was there by right with his flagship, **HMS Duke of York**, close by allowing him to act as host to notable allied leaders.

The most likely means of transport from **Duke of York** to **Missouri** would have been by personal tender on the morning of Sep. 2 - the crewmen of which would have been entertained by the **Missouri** crew until Fraser was ready to depart again.

Most, if not all, senior naval officers with commands either ashore or on nearby vessels other than **USS Missouri** would most probably have been transported to **Missouri** in the same fashion on the morning of Sep. 2. Celebration notwithstanding, they weren't on holiday - they had commands to run and other tasks to execute. All such naval officers were probably hosting visiting officers, of a roughly equivalent rank, from other services or countries, who would have arrived with them that morning.

Comment: And (I've heard this from someone saying his father was among them) there were crews ferrying supplies and people to and from the ships at anchor using landing craft. These ferries also went to Missouri and the crews of them would assist in the loading and unloading.